# jQuery Yes/No Different Link

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I've been pulling my hairs trying to get this to work with jQuery's innerhtml, Although some people told me its not recommended to use, its for a small part of a page so I dont think it will affect site speed and such.

Heres the snippet ive been using:

```
$('input[name|="yesno1"]').change(function () {

    if ($(this).val() == 'YES') {
        $("#div1").hide();
        $("#div2").show();

    } else {

        $("#div2").hide();
        $("#div1").show();
    }
});
```

And The code:

```
function replace3() {
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = "<b>3. </b>";
    document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = "<b>Would You Like To Try It? </b>";
    document.getElementById('answer1').innerHTML = "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"yesno1\" id=\"dl\" value=\"YES\" /> Yes";
    document.getElementById('answer2').innerHTML = "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"yesno1\" id=\"dl\" value=\"NO\" /> No";
    document.getElementById('nextbutton').innerHTML = "<div id=\"div1\">Default Link</div> <div id=\"div2\">No Answer Link</div>";    
}
```

Im trying to set the radio button YES/ NO with a different link, I tried using the above on a standard html page and it works, but it fails here when its using within the **innerHTML** tags.

Comment: You need to post a fiddle, or some more explanation on how the replace() function is being called.

Comment: Not meant to be a solution for your problem (which i dont understand) but instead of `document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = "<b>3. </b>";` use `$('#number').html("<b>3. </b>");` for jQuery style accessing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options:

1. **(recommended)** You could bind that `click` event `on` on the parent element. This is the best method because irrespective of the number of `input` inside its the parent the `click` is always attached to the parent and that makes it DRY and more performant.

   ```
   $("Parent of input").on('click', 'input[name|="yesno1"]', function(){
       if ($(this).val() == 'YES') {
         $("#div1").hide();
         $("#div2").show();
       } else {
         $("#div2").hide();
         $("#div1").show();
      }
   });
   ```
2. You could place your event handler with `$('input[name|="yesno1"]')` as selector as the last statement inside the `replace3()` method. At that time your `input` elements would be in DOM and so you can bind the click handler to the element.

   ```
     function replace3() {
         document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = "<b>3. </b>";
         document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = "<b>Would You Like To Try It? </b>";
         document.getElementById('answer1').innerHTML = "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"yesno1\" id=\"dl\" value=\"YES\" /> Yes";
         document.getElementById('answer2').innerHTML = "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"yesno1\" id=\"dl\" value=\"NO\" /> No";
         document.getElementById('nextbutton').innerHTML = "<div id=\"div1\">Default Link</div> <div id=\"div2\">No Answer Link</div>";    

         //your change event here
         $('input[name|="yesno1"]').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'YES') {
             $("#div1").hide();
             $("#div2").show();
            } else {
             $("#div2").hide();
             $("#div1").show();
            }
         });    
    }
   ```
3. You could bind this element (`input`) to the `document` object which always exists, even before jquery is loaded.

   ```
   $(document).on('change', 'input[name|="yesno1"]', function() { 
    if(this.value =='YES') {     
      $("#div1").hide();
      $("#div2").show();     
    } else {    
      $("#div2").hide();
      $("#div1").show();
    }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try using event delegation with `on`(jq 1.7+) or `live`(older) for the elements replaced with innerHTML or bind the event after they are replaced. Seems like you are binding the events either before they exist in DOM or you are replacing them again which causes the event to be lost on them.

```
 $(document).on('change', 'input[name|="yesno1"]', function() { // Use the common container instead of document.
    if(this.value =='YES') {     
       $("#div1").hide();
       $("#div2").show();       

    } else {

       $("#div2").hide();
       $("#div1").show();
    }
 });
```

Also probably you can reduce it down to

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name|="yesno1"]', function() { // Use the common container instead of document.

   $("#div1, #div2").toggle(); // provided you show1 and hide one at the startup, with the default radio checked.

 });
```

If you want to do jquery way

```
function replace3() {
    $('#number').html("<b>3. </b>");
    $('#question').html("<b>Would You Like To Try It? </b>");
   // ....
}
```

**[event-delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**